# new to R, and I am getting an error running my function

Tags: r, function

```
random_players <- function(K){
  R_two_players <- sample(c(1:13), 2, replace = FALSE) 
  #select two 2 players randomly
  i <- R_two_players[1] 
  j <- R_two_players[2]
  new_rating <- elo_Rating(i, j, K)
  # call the function from q-6 in order to have 
  # access to probability of lose or success of players i and j   
  return(new_rating)
} 

ratings_updated<-matrix(nrow=13, ncol=10000) # is in my global environment

simulate_tournament<-function(K=0.02,n=10000) {  #n is the number of games we are simulating 
ratings_updated<-matrix(nrow=13, ncol=10000) 
for (i in 1:n) {
updated_rate<<-random_players(K)  #calling the function from function before to get the new_rating
ratings_updated[,i]<<-updated_rate
}
return(ratings_updated)
}
```

I am getting an "Error in ratings_updated[, i] <- updated_rate :
incorrect number of subscripts on matrix". I would like my matrix "ratings_updated" gets updated every-time I go to the loop.

Comment: Don't use `<<-`. That's modifying objects *outside* of the function. Keep your changes inside the function, and then `return` what you need (which you're already doing).

Comment: Hi Gregor, I need to have the change in the global environment where my matrix is and would like to add the new data eveytime to the new column of my matrix but what should I do to run and not get an error.

Comment: Can you share the `random_players` function?  My best guess is that it sometimes returns something of the wrong size, i.e., not a vector of length 13. I can't really debug further without that.

Comment: The normal way to update your matrix every time your function is called is to assign the result, `ratings_updated <- simulate_tournament(...)`

Comment: random_players<-function(K){
R_two_players<-sample(c(1:13),2,replace =FALSE)  #select two 2 players randomly
i<-R_two_players[1]
j<-R_two_players[2]
new_rating<-elo_Rating(i,j,K) 
  #call the function from q-6 in order to have access to probability of lose or success of players i and j
return(new_rating)
}

Comment: Okay, I edited that in to the question . I still can't run/debug your code because `random_players` has a new dependency - `elo_Rating`, which I don't have.... any chance you could share that and any other dependencies?